# Null check operator used on a null value is thrown whenever custom widget is used

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I have a main.dart file that handles to return to the login screen or the logged in screen according to the status of user.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: AuthService.firebase().initialize(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    try {
      final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
      final userEmail = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email;

      if (user != null) {
        return FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: checkEmail(user, userEmail),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == true ||
                user.isEmailVerified == true) {
              updateEmailVerification(userEmail);

              return LoggedMainView();
            } else {
              AuthService.firebase().sendEmailVerification();
              return AlertSnackbar(
                  statusColor: Colors.red,
                  messageStatus: 'Snap!',
                  message: 'Email is not Verified',
                  secondaryMessage:
                      'Verifiction link has been sent to mail.');
            }
          },
        );
      } else {
        return LoginView();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return LoginView();
    }
  },
  );
  }
```

So this code checks if the user is logged in or not and if user is logged in then it checks if the email is verified or not. I have used two methods for email verification for the initial registration user is redirected to otp window to verify there otp sent in mail and upon verificaiont a field in firestore isVerified is updated to true. If user doesn't verify and try to login again It again checks if either of the meethod is verified i.e is email or the firebase email verification method. Now If not verified from the otp then now firebase email verification is sent. Now when I am trying to show my custom AlertSnacbar in the login screen then an error is thrown shoing **"Null check operator used on a null value"**. But If I replace that snacbar with return LoginView(); it works perfectly fine. I am getting anywhere as the widget has no any connection with the null checking statements above. What could be the reason?

I tried putting widget in the same file. I tried to return a plain snackbar with just message. But nothing seems to work and same error is thrown always.

Logs from the error:

```
I/flutter ( 8066): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8066): The following _TypeError was thrown building 
FutureBuilder<bool>(state:
I/flutter ( 8066): _FutureBuilderState<bool>#ff56f):
I/flutter ( 8066): Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter ( 8066): 
I/flutter ( 8066): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 8066):   FutureBuilder<bool> 
FutureBuilder:file:///D:/my-flutter-app/lib/main.dart:47:20
I/flutter ( 8066): 
I/flutter ( 8066): When the exception was thrown, this was the 
stack:
I/flutter ( 8066): #0      _SnackBarState.initState 
(package:flutter/src/material/snack_bar.dart:508:21)
I/flutter ( 8066): #1      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5430:55)
I/flutter ( 8066): #2      ComponentElement.mount 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5273:5)
I/flutter ( 8066): #3      Element.inflateWidget 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4182:16)
I/flutter ( 8066): #4      Element.updateChild 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:20)
I/flutter ( 8066): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5322:16)
I/flutter ( 8066): #6      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:11)
I/flutter ( 8066): #7      Element.rebuild 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5016:7)
I/flutter ( 8066): #8      StatefulElement.update 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5485:5)
I/flutter ( 8066): #9      Element.updateChild 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3685:15)
I/flutter ( 8066): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5322:16)
```

Here is the code to my alert snack bar that I have returned in the main.dart file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class AlertSnackbar extends SnackBar {
AlertSnackbar({
super.key,
required Color? statusColor,
required String? messageStatus,
required String? message,
required String? secondaryMessage,
}) : super(
      content: SizedBox(
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            "$messageStatus",
            style:
                const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 
       FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                "$message",
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              Text(
                "$secondaryMessage",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
      ),
      backgroundColor: statusColor,
      );
      }
```

Comment: There is no null-check operator (postfix `!`) used in any of the code you've shown.  What is the stacktrace for the error?  What is the code it refers to?

Comment: I have updated my questions with the logs and stack trace.

Comment: The alertsnackbar is returned inside the FutureBuilder. Could that be a problem ?

Comment: Please add the code of alert snackbar

Comment: I have updated again with my alertsnackbar code. Please have a look

Comment: I'm not sure which version of the Flutter SDK you're using, but the failure seems to be from [`widget.animation!.addStatusListener(_onAnimationStatusChanged);`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/367f9ea16bfae1ca451b9cc27c1366870b187ae2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/snack_bar.dart#L508).  I think `animation` is usually expected to be set from [`ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldMessengerState/showSnackBar.html), which calls [`Snackbar.withAnimation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar/withAnimation.html).

Comment: Do you override `Snackbar.withAnimation`? (You probably should since it otherwise will return an instance of the original `Snackbar`.) Or, if you're not using `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()`, you'll need to ensure that `animation` is initialized some other way.

Comment: `future: AuthService.firebase().initialize(),` is broken.  Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: @jamesdlin I haven't used override. And I haven't used animation too.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz How to build a FutureBuilder without a future parameter ?

Comment: Did you watch my video?

Comment: @Profesor While you don't use an animation, but a `SnackBar` *expects* `animation` to be set.

Comment: @jamesdlin I see. So it doesn't matter If I use it or not. Hence I should use ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar() for returning.

Comment: @Profesor As I explained, `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()` should be used to show a snackbar, but it calls `Snackbar.withAnimation` which, if you neglect to override it, will create a new `Snackbar` instance (i.e., *not* an instance of your `AlertSnackbar`).

Comment: @jamesdlin I am confused little bit just a beginner so. Can you provide me little snippet on how to return the snackbar ?